# add attribute using filecodemodel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, attributes

I am trying to add few attributes to a class using an addin. I can get the following code to working, except that I want the attributes on new lines each contained within []. How do I do this?

```
if (element2.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction)
{
    CodeFunction2 func = (CodeFunction2)element2;
    if (func.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic)
    {
        func.AddAttribute("Name", "\"" + func.Name + "\"", 0);
        func.AddAttribute("Active", "\"" + "Yes" + "\"", 0);
        func.AddAttribute("Priority", "1", 0);
    }
}
```

Attributes are added to the public method like

```
[Name("TestMet"), Active("Yes"), Priority(1)]
```

Where as I want it as

```
[Name("TestMet")]
[Active("Yes")]
[Priority(1)]
public void TestMet()
{}
```

Also how can I add an attribute without any value, like [`PriMethod`].

Answer (score 0):

Signature for the method you are using:

```
CodeAttribute AddAttribute(
    string Name,
    string Value,
    Object Position
)
```

1. If you don't need value for the attribute, use `String.Empty` field for the second parameter
2. Third parameter is for the `Position`. In your code you set this parameter three times for the `0`, and VS thinks that this is the same attribute. So use some index, like that:

`func.AddAttribute("Name", "\"" + func.Name + "\"", 1);

  func.AddAttribute("Active", "\"" + "Yes" + "\"", 2);

  func.AddAttribute("Priority", "1", 3);`

If you don't want to use index, use `-1` value - this will add new attribute at the end of collection.

[More on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5x7z322f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the respone. I did try using 0,1 and 2 for relative positions, yet the position was the same as above.

Comment: I also tried string.empty. Thta gave me PriMethod() and not just PriMethod.

Comment: @user393148 Try to use `-1`. Also I forgot to mention, that index starts from `1` here, so try to use 1, 2, 3.

Comment: No luck. I just tried (0, -1, -1 ) (1, -1, -1), (1,2,3) and yet the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

The base `AddAttribute` method does not support this, so I wrote an extension method to do this for me:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddUniqueAttributeOnNewLine(this CodeFunction2 func, string name, string value)
    {
        bool found = false;
        // Loop through the existing elements and if the attribute they sent us already exists, then we will not re-add it.
        foreach (CodeAttribute2 attr in func.Attributes)
        {
            if (attr.Name == name)
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            // Get the starting location for the method, so we know where to insert the attributes
            var pt = func.GetStartPoint();
            EditPoint p = (func.DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("") as TextDocument).CreateEditPoint(pt);

            // Insert the attribute at the top of the function
            p.Insert(string.Format("[{0}({1})]\r\n", name, value));

            // Reformat the document, so the new attribute is properly aligned with the function, otherwise it will be at the beginning of the line.
            func.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument");
        }

    }
}
```